# Spring Boot JPA Database Choice

Tags: postgresql, jpa, spring-boot

How can I start a stand-alone Spring Boot JPA application -- not via cli -- with a choice of databases to get data, e.g., localhost:5432/my_db; or 192.168.1.100:5432/our_db, or example.com:5432/their_db?

Mine currently uses the one in the application.properties file that contains:

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/my_db
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: How is the choice going to be made? What's the criteria?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you probably need to configure username and password as well, I recommend creating separate `application-mydatasource.properties` files for each data source configuration. You will then activate the datasource you want to use based on setting the active profile. You can set the active profile either in `application.properties` (`spring.profiles.active`) or via a command line argument:

```
$ java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=mydatasource demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

The `application-mydatasource.properties` will then override any properties in your `application.properties`. I believe you will also need to set `spring.profiles=` to the list of profiles available.

See [Profile specific properties](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties).

Comment: I thought property files had to be in this format: `application-{profile}.properties`. Also, `spring.profiles=` should be `spring.profiles.active=`, correct?

Comment: @EricFrancis, you're right about the name of the properties file. I corrected my answer. But since I'm passing in the active profile as a command-line, I don't have to specify the active profile in spring.profiles.active.

Comment: "A YAML file is actually a sequence of documents separated by --- lines, and each document is parsed separately to a flattened map.

If a YAML document contains a spring.profiles key, then the profiles value (comma-separated list of profiles) is fed into the Spring Environment.acceptsProfiles() and if any of those profiles is active that document is included in the final merge (otherwise not)." The `spring.profiles` property is only valid within a YAML file.

Comment: See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-change-configuration-depending-on-the-environment in the reference.

Answer (score 0):

Another options besides the @Profile label, that you will have to declare in every enviroment that you will deploy the application, you could use in Spring Boot the label:

@ConditionalOnProperty(name="propertyName", havingValue="propertyValue")

And declare a property to decide wich database you want to load in each case!

Hope being helping!!